# Can we set value to props like setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to set value for props, can we set value to pros like **this.setProps({status : false})**

Answer (score 2):

No, that's an antipattern. props are supposed to be constant upon component declaration. If you have *variables*, then you should define them in the component's state.

Comment: could you say the same about the redux paradigm?

Comment: @eltonkamami I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What about the redux paradigm relates to what I'm saying about component state?

Comment: Redux updates components passing them new props that reflect the current application state and forcing a rerender . Based on your answer that is an antipattern too right?

Comment: @eltonkamami No, that's not an antipattern. props are handed down from parent components to child components and if a parent component re-renders a child with new props, then the child component is destroyed and re-created which means that the props are still considered constant upon component declaration. This way, the child component can use lifecycle methods like `componentWillUnmount()` and `componentWillMount()` to have a chance to clean up and re-initialize its state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setState()` or you can update child props in parent component